# Flutter floor database Future bool action in DAO file?

Tags: database, sqlite, flutter, floor

While using floor database can we set an action which will turn as a boolean like below example?

```
Future<bool> isItAdded(in user_id) async{
    var = dbClient = await db;
    List<Map> list = await dbClient.rawQuery{SELECT * FROM Users WHERE user_id}, [user_id]}
    return list.lenght > 0 ? true : false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write DAO object:

```
@dao
abstract class UsersDao {
  @Query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = :userId')
  Future<List<User>> findUsers(Int userId);
}
```

Before that you neeed to create entity:

```
@Entity(tableName: 'users')
class User{
  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate: true)
  final int id;

  @ColumnInfo(name: 'user_id')
  final int userId;
}
```

Also you need to create database access object:

```
part 'database.g.dart'; // the generated code will be there

 @Database(version: 1, entities: [User])
 abstract class AppDatabase extends FloorDatabase {
   UsersDao get usersDao;
 }
```

Then generate additional code by command:

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner build
```

And then write check function inside database access object:

```
Future<bool> isItAdded(in user_id) async {
    List<User> list = await usersDao.findUsers(user_id);
    return list.lenght > 0;
}
```

The best solution is not to add **user_id** column and use only unique **id** column.